# quick question about TF

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the differential drive package it says

```
    tf -

    Broadcasts the transform between the odometry frame and the robot's base_link.
```

My question is what is the odometry frame? is the the transformation between base_link and the world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64582/quick-question-about-tf/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Odometry is the frame of robot's odometry reading. This transform is generally generated by robot itself. Base link of robot is defined w.r.t to odometry. Then odometry is defined w.r.t to map/world, whatever is the fixed frame. Transform between odometry and map/world is to be defined explicitly unless some mapping packages like gmapping is used.

Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0